# Diffuse reflection : why black material has 0 in material's 'k diffuse' constant?

Tags: rendering, glsl, unity-game-engine, shader

I'm learning to write shader program from scratch and now I'm at diffuse lighting. Currently the equation is

```
Diffuse Intensity = Intensity of light * 'k' diffuse constant of material * (dot product of surface's normal vector and light direction vector)
```

The thing is, I've read that for white material the k constant is 1 and if the material is black then the k is 0. Which is not the case of real world because my black object **does** get lighter when I expose it to light source. Why the algorithm is like this?

I'm studying from this link which teaches how to write GLSL in Unity. I can set up the scene easier to experimenting with shader in Unity.
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Unity/Diffuse_Reflection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lighting models in computer graphics are only simplifications/approximations of the reality.
Most introductions start with the [Phong model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_reflection_model). You resource uses only the diffuse part from this. If the shader is extended with specular light you could get the effect of having a black object with specular highlights on it.

You real world objects reflections are probably much more complex than could be express with only diffuse and specular components from the Phong model.

It is also non-trivial to find real world surfaces that reflect only diffuse light ([lambertian reflectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambertian_reflection#Examples)).